# Not joining a company after signing offer letter

Tags: employment, workplace, singapore

I have been working in Singapore on S-Pass for last 11 months in an IOT product company. I got an offer from a services company in SG, they got me an Employment Pass and I have to join the on x date.

Another company of IoT product for which I gave an interview few months back came back with an offer on x - 3 days.

Now the services company is saying that they will black list me as an employee to the ministry of manpower and will file a civil lawsuit if I do not join them on x date.

And hence I am being pushed to join the services company on x date. Can anyone suggest if they can actually blacklist me and file a lawsuit against me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest if they can actually blacklist me and file a
>   lawsuit against me?

I am not knowledgeable of Singapore law, but what that company tells you sounds in extortion and does not seem to have a legal basis.

The [Employment Act](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/EmA1968) in its section [Notice of termination of contract](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/EmA1968?ProvIds=pr10-) states

> (3)  The notice to terminate the service of a person who is employed
>   under a contract of service shall be not less than
>
> — (a) one day’s notice if he has been so employed for less than 26
>   weeks;

You have been employed there for zero days, that is, less than 26 weeks. Therefore, one day's notice would suffice.

I encourage you to read the entire Employment Act so as to identify what provisions might be applicable to your situation. From my reading of the aforementioned excerpt, the company's stance as you describe it seems devoid of merit and indicative of how you would be treated on a regular basis if you join that company.

Comment: Thanks Inaki. I told them straight no today and they mellowed down. They are now okay with me moving on.

Comment: @HarshVardhan Well done! Just for precaution, consider sending them an email (or printed letter, if they sign a copy as receipt) reflecting that you have notified them. It is always better to have things in writing. It is with email evidence how I [disproved](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/viggers-v-pacha_74.html) the false accusations my former employer (an IT intermediary from India) made about me at the Univ. of Michigan (pending review at [SCOTUS](https://www.supremecourt.gov/search.aspx?filename=/docket/docketfiles/html/public/17-1576.html) ). Best wishes on your new job position.